# How to use Matlab webread with 2 http headers

Tags: matlab, api, parse-platform, http-headers

I need to do this GET call with matlab:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: my_AppKEY" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: my_APIKEY" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

(this is a basic request to parse.com)

In matlab 2014b I have the function [webread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) which becomes a [weboptions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html) struct.

I think the correct way of setting a header for the request is like this:

```
myHeaders1 = weboptions('KeyName', 'X-Parse-Application-Id', 'KeyValue' , 'my_KEY')
```

The thing is... I can only set 1 header using this syntax. **How can I set 2 or more headers to be used in webread?**

Comment: a side note: why don't you call `curl` through [`system`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html)?

Comment: strange that the new function `webread` doesn't have this functionality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either [call curl from within Matlab](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49345-calling-curl-from-within-matlab) if you load right library files or instead you can use [urlread2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35693-urlread2)